# How to load and destroy maps on panning than loading it completely on load

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

I am using mapbox with a tile server. I want to load maps while panning and destroy the loaded region when out of screen (assuming that this will not make the map and the browser very light.)

How am i suppose to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the javascript api of Mapbox with a tilelayer, you could set the `unloadInvisibleTiles` option of that tilelayer.

> If true, all the tiles that are not visible after panning are removed (for better performance). true by default on mobile WebKit, otherwise false.

Setting the option when instanciating the layer:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-20v6611k', {
    'unloadInvisibleTiles': true
});
```

Or if you instanciate the map and layer at once:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-4l7djmvo', {
    'tileLayer': {
        'unloadInvisibleTiles': true
    }
});
```

Here's the reference for `L.mapbox.map`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-map/ and here's the reference for `L.mapbox.tileLayer`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-tilelayer/

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with Open Layer?

Comment: That's kinda out of the scope of your question and OpenLayers is out of my comfortzone :) But after a quick glance at the API for [ol.layer.Tile](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html) i think it's not.

Comment: I am just wondering that before leaflet, someone must have achieved this in openlayers. Anyways thanx iH8

Comment: No thanks, always welcome. Maybe it's already done through the use of a plugin or something, i can't find nothing about it in the API documentation. If you want to be sure i would suggest you open a new question. Good luck!